# What is the Python idiom for chaining tensor products?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Numpy's [`outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) flattens its arguments. As a result it isn't possible to chain `outer` to implement the mathematical definition of the [(matrix) tensor product](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1507752/12400), for example as is possible [in Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct.html) with

```
TensorProduct[a, b, c]
```

However it's possible to "recover" this functionality by reshaping the result with the dimensions of the arguments, with something like

```
np.outer(a, np.outer(b, c)).reshape(a.shape + b.shape + c.shape)
```

But I wonder if this is really the right approach. Is there an API I'm missing that already does this. Perhaps TensorFlow has something I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`outer` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer) of NumPy ufuncs doesn't flatten:

```
outer = numpy.multiply.outer
result = outer(a, outer(b, c))
```

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: It's a NumPy-specific function type NumPy uses to take operations like addition, multiplication, negation, etc. and provide implicit C-level loops to apply them naturally over arrays. You usually don't need to focus on the details, but you can [read more about the details](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The code for `np.outer` is just:

```
return multiply(a.ravel()[:, newaxis], b.ravel()[newaxis,:], out)
```

So for 2 1d arrays it's the same as `a[:,None] * b[None,:]`, in other words the element wise product of a (n,1) array with a (1,m), producing a (n,m).  That 2nd `None` is automatic, but I like to include it for human clarity.

The same idea can be extended to a 2d array (yielding a 3d), or several arrays.

```
In [65]: a,b,c = np.ones(2),np.ones(3),np.ones(4)
In [66]: np.outer(a, np.outer(b, c)).reshape(a.shape + b.shape + c.shape)
Out[66]: 
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]])
In [67]: _.shape
Out[67]: (2, 3, 4)
In [68]: a[:,None,None]*b[None,:,None]*c[None,None,:]
Out[68]: 
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]])
```

More generally:

```
In [69]: a,b,c = np.ones((2,2)),np.ones((1,3)),np.ones(4)
In [70]: np.outer(a, np.outer(b, c)).reshape(a.shape + b.shape + c.shape)
....
In [71]: _.shape
Out[71]: (2, 2, 1, 3, 4)

In [73]: a[...,None,None,None]*b[None,None,...,None]*c[None,None,...]
...
In [74]: _.shape
Out[74]: (2, 2, 1, 3, 4)
```

and with the ufunc `outer`:

```
In [77]: np.multiply.outer(a, np.multiply.outer(b,c)).shape
Out[77]: (2, 2, 1, 3, 4)
```

The explicit broadcasting is wordier than this ufunc outer, but gives you more control.

Another method:

```
In [84]: np.einsum('ij,kl,m',a,b,c).shape
Out[84]: (2, 2, 1, 3, 4)
```